# Return list of list from Python to JS

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am doing some calculation on my python code. As a result, I get list of list similar to what I have here

```
data = [
 [{"Count": 33874, "range": "-10"}, {"Count": 19961, "range": "-9"}], 
 [{"Count": 46831, "range": "8"}, {"Count": 62326, "range": "9"}]
]
```

I want to return this to my JS? I am currently using `jsonify({"list":data})` but this does not work.

## My python code

```
@app.route('/readRatingFiles', methods = ['POST'])
def get_post_MlModel():
    data = compute()
    return jsonify({"list":data})
```

## My JS code

```
  $.post("/readRatingFiles", {
  }).done(function(data) {
      indexGot = data.index
      textDict[indexGot] = data.results;
  });
```

Comment: Where is this code executing? I'm not very familiar with any environment that can run Python and javascript natively together.

Comment: Can you describe "does not work"? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This jsonify is about Flask API, jsonfify package...? Please give us more details.

Comment: updated my post. Please see the details on the post above

Comment: The code returns an array of arrays. What is the expected result of `indexGot = data.index`?

Comment: @guest271314 even when I define index: JSON.stringify() it does not work

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` log at `.done()`? Where is `textDict` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call was malformed.

Look again at what you're returning: `jsonify({"list": data})`. The callback function returns the JSON object, but you never get the key. `data` in the callback is not the same as the `data` variable in Python. The correct way should be:

```
$.post("/readRatingFiles", {
}).done(function(response) {
     data = response['list'];
     indexGot = data.index;
     textDict[indexGot] = data.results;
});
```

Not entirely sure what the rest of your JavaScript code means, but I trust you know what you're doing. :P